# Problema con threads en python.

Tags: python, hilos

Estoy teniendo algunos problemas para terminar unos threads.

Mi programa cuenta con una función runthreads():

```
def runThreads():
    """
    Creates and runs threads.
    """

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=netstatCapture, name='netstatCapture')
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=tasklistCapture, name='tasklistCapture')
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=capture_from_wifi(), name='WiFiCapture')
    t4 = threading.Thread(target=capture_from_eth(), name='EthCapture')

    t1.daemon = True
    t1.start()
    t2.daemon = True
    t2.start()
    t3.daemon = True
    t3.start()
    t4.daemon = True
    t4.start()
```

esta funcion es llamada por mi función main():

```
runThreads()
```

Luego, defino a main() como otro thread, de forma que al terminar los threeads definidos en runThreads() no termine toda la ejecucion:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main = threading.Thread(target=main, name='main_function')
  main.start()
```

El tema es que si yo quiero terminar la ejecución, por ejemplo con ctrl+c, los threads definidos en runThreads() no terminan..
Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Gracias!!!

PD: estoy usando Python 2.7 y la librería threading

Comment: Por norma general matar hilos por fuerza bruta  no es fácil ni recomendable. No obstante, si tus hilos implementan algún mainloop para llevar a cabo su tarea es muy fácil detenerlos de forma segura usando un `threading.Event` por ejemplo desde el hilo principal.

Answer (score 1):

En python 2.7 es muy problemático. El Ctrl-C envía una señal que sólo es enviada al hilo principal. Tendrías que instalar un manejador de señales (`signal()`) en ese hilo, que la capture, y ponga alguna variable global booleana que los demás hilos consulten periódicamente para saber que deben terminar. En python 3 la señal es en cambio enviada a todos los hilos, y manejada por defecto por el intérprete, de modo que pulsando Ctlr-C dos veces, mata todos los hilos.

En cualquier caso, aún en Python3, lo razonable es no matar un hilo "sin más", porque podría estar en medio de alguna operación importante, sino señalarle que acabe cuando pueda, mediante alguna variable global.

## Ejemplo

Aquí tienes un ejemplo que usa la técnica descrita. He implementado las funciones `netstatCapture` y `tasklistCapture` como bucles infinitos que contienen un `time.sleep()`. Tus funciones también deberían llamar periódicamente a `time.sleep()`, puesto que esta es una función interrumpible que "despertará" ante Ctrl-C. En cualquier caso el bucle no es infinito del todo, sino que consulta la variable global `terminar` para decidir cuándo acabar.

Esta variable global es escrita desde el manejador de señal apropiado, el cual se registra en el programa principal mediante `signal.signal()`.

Observa que el hilo principal debe mantenerse "vivo", pues en python 2 es el único que recibirá la señal Ctrl-C y si este hilo muriera, la señal se perdería y todo el esquema fallaría. Para mantenerlo vivo, le meto en otro bucle de espera, como a los restantes hilos:

```py
# coding: utf-8
import threading
import time
import signal

terminar = False

def procesarCtrlC(*args):
    """Manejador para la señal SIGINT"""
    global terminar
    terminar = True
    print("Detectado Ctrl-C con parametros {}".format(args))

def netstatCapture():
    print("Arrancando netstatCapture")
    while not terminar:
        time.sleep(2)
    print("Terminando netstatCapture")

def tasklistCapture():
    print("Arrancando tasklistCapture")
    while not terminar:
        time.sleep(2)
    print("Terminando tasklistCapture")


def runThreads():
    """
    Creates and runs threads.
    """

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=netstatCapture, name='netstatCapture')
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=tasklistCapture, name='tasklistCapture')

    t1.daemon = True
    t1.start()
    t2.daemon = True
    t2.start()

def main():
    print("Función principal")
    runThreads()
    print("Hios lanzados")
    while not terminar:
        time.sleep(4)
    print("Terminando main")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # La siguiente línea "instala" el manejador de señal
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, procesarCtrlC)
    main = threading.Thread(target=main, name='main_function')
    main.start()
    while not terminar:
        time.sleep(3)
```

Esta solución también funcionará en Python 3, aunque en el caso de Python 3 funcionaría igualmente un Ctrl-C sin necesidad de programar nada especial, si bien eso mataría los hilos en cualquier momento, mientras que el enfoque anterior sólo terminan los hilos cuando vuelvan a iterar en su `while()` y descubran la condición de terminación, lo que suele ser preferible pues así tienen la oportunidad de liberar recursos, etc.